# SQL Where Condition having 15+ different strings for one column

Tags: sql, performance, select, conditional-statements, netezza

I would like to implement for 1 column multiple specific parameters like:

```
select * from table1 
where column1 = a or column1 = b or column1  = c ...
```

Can it be done in a better way (the SQL Statement in Use is **over 10 lines long** with the OR statements it'll grow another 10 lines O.o and it'll make the code ***much slower!***)

Comment: For readability you could use the operator IN. The performance though would not be better.

Comment: `column1 IN (a ,b ,c, ...)` should work for many SQL databases.

Comment: If you're worried about performance then adding an index on column1 might help, but using 'IN' is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Are a, b, c etc literals/values, or other columns?

Comment: Ive heard the fastest way SQL it could be processed it would include UNION ALL, though  for readability IN as mentioned in comments already.

Comment: There are 40 columns, but these values i mentioned are for one column @jarlh

Comment: Put a, b, c etc in a separate table, create index, join.

Comment: do you mean by creating external tables ? @jarlh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where column in ( . . . );
```

The `in` list is pretty equivalent to a bunch of `or` conditions.  There are some nuances.  For instance, all the values in the `in` list will be converted to the same type.  If one is a number and the rest are strings, then all will be converted to strings -- perhaps generating an error.

For performance, you want an index on `t(column)`.

Comment: This helps out the most from the visibility of the code, sadly it doesnt assist with the performance speed, for that best would be UNION ALL by selecting those specific parameters, though how much lines should be extra written, that ill have to check.